# Best practices for version information?

Tags: language-agnostic, versioning

I am currently working on automating/improving the release process for packaging my shop's entire product. Currently the product is a combination of:

- Java server-side codebase
- XML configuration and application files
- Shell and batch scripts for administrators
- Statically served HTML pages
- and some other stuff, but that's most of it

All or most of which have various versioning information contained in them, used for varying purposes. Part of the release packaging process involves doing a lot of finding, grep'ing and sed'ing (in scripts) to update the information. This glue that packages the product seems to have been cobbled together in an organic, just-in-time manner, and is pretty horrible to maintain. For example, some Java methods create Date objects for the time of release, the arguments for which are updated by a textual replacement, without compiler validation... just, urgh.

I'm trying avoid giving examples of actual software used (i.e. CVS, SVN, ant, etc.) because I'd like to avoid the "use xyz's feature to do this" and concentrate more on general practices. I'd like to blame shoddy design for the problem, but if I had to start again, still using varying technologies, I'd be unsure how best to go about handling this, beyond laying down conventions.

My questions is, are there any best practices or hints and tips for maintaining and updating versioning information across different technologies, filetypes, platforms and version control systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, to complete Craig Angus's answer, the rule of thumb here should be to ***not include any meta-informations in your normal delivery files***, but to report those meta-data (version number, release date, and so on) into *one* special file -- included in the release --.

That helps when you use one VCS (Version Control System) tool from the development to homologation to pre-production.
That means whenever you load a workspace (either for developing, or for testing or for preparing a release into production), it is the versionning tool which gives you all the details.

When you prepare a delivery (a set of packaged files), you should ask that VCS tool about every meta-information you want to keep, and write them in a special file itself included into the said set of files.

That delivery should be packaged in an external directory (outside any workspace) and:

- copied to a shared directory (or a maven repository) if it is a *non-official* release (but just a quick packaging for helping the team next door who is waiting for your delivery). That way you can make 10 or 20 delivers a day, it does not matter: they are easily disposable.
- imported into the VCS in order to serve as official deliveries, and in order to be deployed easily since all you need is to ask the versionning tool for the right version of the right deliver, and you can begin to deploy it.

Note: I just described a release management process mostly used for many inter-dependant projects. For one small single project, you can skip the import in the VCS tool and store your deliveries elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Create a properties file that contains the version number and have all of the different components reference the properties file

- Java files can reference the properties through
- XML can use includes?
- HTML can use a JavaScript to write the version number from the properties in the HTML
- Shell scripts can read in the file

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Craig Angus' ones include the version of tools used.